# Is it possible to use vs2010 c++ and use Qt for all platforms?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

What i hear about Qt, is that it is providing an operating system independent layer.
To do well most tasks a coder normally does. To perform at best the code has to be c++
While there is also mono providing some translation to c++ and there Dot24 an android c# kernel.

Currently the things we do, cannt be done in mono, for hardware reasons.
So i am thinking of going back to pure C++ and QT instead of C#.

Now what i am wondered about
By itself c++ is a standard and should also be idenpendent for linux/windows/unix/microboards/Ce devices etc etc.

But if i would write using VS2010 c++ and QT would i still have advantage my code would run on a wide range of platforms ? . As visual studio, creates a windows based exe? Or should i use also another IDE to write truely independent c++ with Qt?

Comment: No, there are embedded systems that do not have enough memory for QT or do not have mouse and displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to develop Qt applications in Visual Studio that can be used on other platforms. For example for my work in medical imaging research, I develop all of my Qt based applications in Visual Studio 2010 with the visual studio project files generated using CMake and at times build some of these applications in linux under QtCreator or KDevelop using the same CMakeLists.txt to generate project files for for these IDEs. As long as I stay away from platform specific code the porting is not that difficult.

Comment: I am thankful that my answer was accepted however I believe Matteo Italia had a better answer. I posted an answer because I wanted to share my experience a little since I have done this for 5+ years.

Answer (score 3):

C++ is a compiled language, whatever IDE/compiler you'll use it will produce executables for a certain platform. But the point of Qt is that, as far as you avoid platform-specific code, your sources can be recompiled on the various platforms, generating a different executable for each supported platform. So, using VC++ is not a limitation as far as sources are concerned.

The limitation comes instead from the build system: Visual C++ uses its own format for project files, which is not compatible with makefiles & co. So, if you started your project as a VC++ project, you would have to re-create manually a Makefile or similar to compile on other platforms.

To avoid this kind of problems, Qt provides `qmake`, a tool that, provided a `.pro` file (roughly equivalent to a `.vcproj`), is able to generate build files for various platforms: `.vcproj`/`.dsp` on Windows, Makefile on Linux and OS X, XCode projects on OS X and probably others.

So the point is: you can use Visual Studio, but you should use Qt's build system to be able to port your application to other platforms without any fuss.

Also, you can consider using Qt Creator, which supports directly `.pro` files, has particularly good integration with the Qt features and works on Windows, Linux and OS X; on the downside, I noticed that the debugger in Visual Studio tends to be way better.

Comment: Also in regard to Ben Voigt's comment; is QT able to create a compililation from the project structure visual studio uses. As our versioning and internal documentation system depends on it.

Comment: You mean going from `.vcproj` to `.pro`? I don't think so. But I don't see how it would be useful, write the `.pro` first and let `qmake` generate the `.vcproj` you need from it.

Comment: qmake or any other makefile template system can help, but you'll still have to set the options for each compiler (except for a very few it can translate automatically)

Answer (score 1):

If you have cross-platform C++ code using Qt, you can edit and compile the Windows version using Visual C++ (the compiler that comes in Visual Studio).

Visual C++ still only creates Windows executables, though, so to actually build and run on other platforms, you'll have to get another compiler (but feed in the same source code).

One pain point will be with makefiles: visual Studio has its own project format and cannot process standard makefiles.  Neither do other platforms use Visual Studio projects.  Visual Studio does come with a tool called `nmake` which is similar to POSIX or GNU make, but still not compatible except for the most trivial features.  And of course `cl.exe` uses different command-line switches than other compilers.  So you'll end up maintaining one set of C++ files but two or more sets of makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

In order to develop qt apps qtcreator is the best ide, qtcreator available on linux and mac, so you can open your qt project and build on any platform easily.

Comment: currently for versioning and documentation we depent on vs2010